# Get data from (dr.Reader()) {}

Tags: c#

I wrote a programe for combo box in 'selectedIndexChanged' event to get maximum 'REC' number.
so I encounterd some problem which get result to 'finally'.
I define string variable as 'string x' and 'string max'. I need to get the result to 'finally' segment 
but it gave me some error as 'The name does not exist in 'current contex'.
Please help me to debug this

```
  try
             {                
                 con.Open();
                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Proc_New_check", con);
                 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@PMNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboBox1.Text.Trim();
                 sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                 sda.Fill(dt);
                 string n = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();

                 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Cmbl from tbl2 where records='" +       
                   comboBox1.Text + "'", con);
                 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                 if (dr.Read())
                {
                     string X = dr["Cmbl"].ToString();
                }

                 string max = X +n;

                 con.Close();
             }
             catch (SqlException exc)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Error" + exc);
             }
             finally
             {
                 string REC = max;                  
                 textBox1.Text = REC;                
             }
```

I expect to  get Result as

(string max = AB 00001)

but X and max get Error.

How to get result of 'X' to another place from data Reader

Comment: You need to learn about lexical scopes in C#.

Comment: SqlInjection Alert: please don't build user-supplied values into a sql command string, [use parameters](https://www.bobby-tables.com/adodotnet) instead

Answer (score 0):

You must declare max and X in bigger [scope](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/know-scope-local-variables):

```
string max = string.Empty;
try
{                
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Proc_New_check", con);
     SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@PMNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboBox1.Text.Trim();
     sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     sda.Fill(dt);
     string n = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();

     SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Cmbl from tbl2 where records='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", con);
     SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     string X = string.Empty;         
     if (dr.Read())
     {
         X = dr["Cmbl"].ToString();
     }

     max = X +n;

     con.Close();
 }
 catch (SqlException exc)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Error" + exc);
 }
 finally
 {
     string REC = max;                  
     textBox1.Text = REC;                
 }
```

Comment: This will still generate errors due to lack of definite assignment.

Comment: Errors are same in try segment (X and n)

Comment: Its not read data properly. it gave error as:      An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cmbl

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Yes, you never check if data exists before reading it, so this Exception is expected.